Conditions for interchanging derivative and minimum.
Assume I have the function $g(x, y)$ from $\mathbb{R_+\times R_+}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and let's define $h(y) = \min_x g(x, y)$.
Under what conditions can I swap the minimum and the derivative with respect to the other variable $y$. Or is there a way to compute $h^{'}(y)$?
Thank you!
